# Should this code return a Task or Task<object>?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task, taskcompletionsource

I was reading [The Nature of TaskCompletionSource](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/02/9685804.aspx), a post by Stephen Toub.

```
public static Task RunAsync(Action action)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Object>();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
    {
        try
        {
            action();
            tcs.SetResult(null);
        }
        catch(Exception exc) { tcs.SetException(exc); }
    });
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

---

> Since we no longer care what the type of `T` is, I’ve defaulted to using `Object`. Then, when the `Action` is executed successfully, `SetResult` is still used to transition the `Task` into the `RanToCompletion` final state; however, since the actual result value is irrelevant, `null` is used. **Finally, `RunAsync` returns `Task` rather than `Task<Object>`**. Of course, the instantiated `task`’s type is still `Task<Object>`, but we need not refer to it as such, and the consumer of this method need not care about those implementation details.

I don't particularly understand why the method should return `Task` rather than `Task<object>` (which is why I emphasised the bold sentence). I know the method is set to return `Task` but `tcs` is a `TaskCompletionSource<Object>`, not `TaskCompletionSource` (which is wrong, I think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a non generic `TaskCompletionSource` and considering all you want is a task without a result, the result doesn't matter.
The caller doesn't know and doesn't care in this case that the Task is actually a `Task<object>`, The caller just `await`s it, and gets an exception if there is one. The caller is unaware of the actual result.

This of course is facilitated by the fact that `Task<T>` inherits from `Task`

---

It's also common to find a `Task<bool>` that returns false, or `Task<int>` with 0.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was just about to say the same thing when you updated your answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is no non-generic `TaskCompletionSource` class for creating instances of `Task` which are not instances of `Task<T>`. This leaves two options for the generic type parameter for `TaskCompletionSource<T>` when you don't care about (or are not providing) the return value:

1. Use an arbitrary existing type, such as `object`, as the return type. Set the value to `null` to indicate completion of the task.
2. Use a specific non-public type, and set the value to `null` to indicate completion of the task.

When I create a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` instance for the purpose of providing a `Task` with no return value, I prefer to use a dedicated non-public type to ensure consuming code will not mistake the returned `Task` as an instance of `Task<T>` where the result has meaning.

First, I define the following class (it can be a `private sealed class` if it's nested within another type):

```
internal sealed class VoidResult
{
}
```

Then, instead of using `TaskCompletionSource<object>` for the completion source, I use `TaskCompletionSource<VoidResult>`. Since the `VoidResult` type is not accessible by calling code, the user will be unable to cast the `Task` object to an instance of `Task<VoidResult>`.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't particularly understand why the method should return `Task` rather than `Task<object>`

Because when you return `Task<Object>` it means that when this method completes it will produce some useful value of type `Object`. in this case we're not producing any result, That's why stephen choose to return `Task`.

If we're dealing with `Func<Object>` then returning `Task<Object>` would be appropriate, as `Func` will produce some result, we may choose to return it.

> Why `TaskCompletionSource<Object>`, not `TaskCompletionSource`?

Because there's no such thing. There is no non generic `TaskCompletionSource`.

Answer (score 1):

If you returned a `Task<object>`, then `var result = await RunAsync(...)` would always return `null`, since that's what you're setting the result to.

The client doesn't care about this, so you just return a `Task`.

Ideally, you would use a `TaskCompletionSource` internally, instead of a `TaskCompletionSource<object>`, and just call something like `SetCompleted()` instead of `SetResult(null)`. But such type does not exist.